# Spectrum is the closure of sequence in $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X=l^2$ be space of complex sequences with finite $l^2$ norm. Assume that $(\lambda_n ) \in l^{\infty}$. Define the following operator:

$$ M(x_1,x_2, ...)=(\lambda_1x_1, \lambda_2 x_2, ...) $$

I want to show that Spectrum of $M$ is the closure of $\{\lambda_n \}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

I appreciate any hit. Thanks

Comment: You probably meant $(\lambda_n)\in \ell^\infty$. Talking about the closure of $\{\lambda_n\}$ in $\ell^2$ makes no sense, because that set is not a subset of $\ell^2$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Yes. Exactly. I am going to correct.

Comment: _Again:_ talking about the closure of that set in $\ell^2$ makes no sense, because it is not even a subset of $\ell^2$.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich. Sorry. I mean closure in $\mathbb{R}$.